# How do I mem-aref the output of a meta-object in CFFI

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

I have this function scalar which is a wrapper of the 2 function definitions commented above it.
My ? is how do I mem-aref the output of `(scalar 1 2 3 4)`, which is `#<CV-SCALAR {10044559D3}>`
I think `#<CV-SCALAR {10044559D3}>` is called a Meta-Object

```
    ;; Scalar* cv_create_Scalar(double val0, (double val1, double val2, double val3)
    (defcfun ("cv_create_Scalar" %scalar) scalar
      (val0 :double)
      (val1 :double)
      (val2 :double)
      (val3 :double))


    (define-foreign-type scalar ()
      ((garbage-collect  :reader garbage-collect :initform nil :initarg 
                         :garbage-collect))
      (:actual-type :pointer)
      (:simple-parser scalar))


    (defclass cv-scalar ()
      ((c-pointer :reader c-pointer :initarg :c-pointer)))


    (defmethod translate-to-foreign ((lisp-value cv-scalar) (c-type scalar))
      (c-pointer lisp-value))


    (defmethod translate-from-foreign (c-pointer (c-type scalar))
      (let ((scalar (make-instance 'cv-scalar :c-pointer c-pointer)))
        (when (garbage-collect c-type)
          (tg:finalize scalar (lambda () (del-scalar c-pointer))))
        scalar))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you defclass and defmethods are defined as above you run `(mem-aref (c-pointer a) :int 1)` to mem-aref the return-value